# gvisScatterChart - hAxis.title and vAxis.title not appearing on the plot

Tags: r, googlevis

`hAxis.title` and `vAxis.title` options don't seem to set the axis titles for `gvisScatterChart` in the package `googleVis`.

```
plot(gvisScatterChart(data.frame(x = 3, y = 4), options=list(hAxis.title = 'foo')))
```

"foo" doesn't appear as the horizontal axis title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to pass options to `hAxis` in a dictionary-looking `JSON` object format:

```
plot(gvisScatterChart(data.frame(x = 3, y = 4), options=list(hAxis="{title:'foo'}")))
```

See the examples at the bottom of the [help page](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/googleVis/docs/gvisScatterChart) and this under `hAxis`:

> a JSON object. Default `null`. An     object with members to configure         various horizontal axis elements. To specify properties of this     object, you can use object literal notation, as shown here:
>   {title: 'Hello', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}}